# Gettext and Array Sorting Using Array Map Function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, gettext

I have a registration script and multi-lingual. I have to use gettext function for translation.

```
$countries = $locationObj->getCountries();
```

This code gets country list from database. In database country names are Turkish. For my other language support i have to use gettext.

$countries is an array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [code] => UM
            [country] => ABD Küçük Harici Adaları
            [currency] => USD
            [area_code] => +1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [code] => VI
            [country] => ABD Virjin Adaları
            [currency] => USD
            [area_code] => +1 340
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => AF
            [country] => Afganistan
            [currency] => AFN
            [area_code] => +93
        )
```

If i use gettext function inside foreach loop for options. The country names alphabetic order will be broken. First of all, i have to translate country names later i have to create for each loop.

Can i use array_map function for gettext ? Is it a simple way. Or am i have to create foreach loop and create new data array and sorting this ?

Comment: `Can i use array_map function for gettext ?` -- try it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution at the end. I'm using array_multisort And i create another foreach loop before parsing options. And in this loop i used gettext.

> foreach($countries as $key => $country){
>         $countryNames[$key] = _($country['country']);  }
>         array_multisort($countryNames, SORT_STRING, $countries);

Now my $countries array is sorted for translation.

When parsing options i use gettext function again for translation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of sort function for arrays (even works on multidimensional level).

As example you can use ksort (it manteins index association).

Full list of sort command for array: -> http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php